# In perturbation theory, why is nothing asymptotic to zero?

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory

I'm a physicist who's recently begun studying asymptotics and perturbation theory, and I'm confused as to why nothing can be asymptotic to zero (in the sense of $f(x)\sim 0$ as $x\to x_0$).

Comment: Something _can_ be asymptotic to zero _if and only if_ it is _actually_ zero in some neighborhood of $x_0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short:** because then, $f$ has to be identically $0$ on some open interval around $x_0$, and *that's not a very interesting situation...*

**To see why:**
Let's have a look at the definition of asymptotics:

> We have that $$
> f(x) \sim_{x\to x_0} g(x)
> $$
>   means
>   $$
> f(x)-g(x) =_{x\to x_0} o(g(x))
> $$

which in turn means

> There exists a non-negative function $\varepsilon$ (defined on a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$) such that $\lim_{x\to x_0} \varepsilon(x) = 0$ and $\lvert f(x) - g(x)\rvert \leq \varepsilon(x) \lvert g(x)\rvert$ for all $x\in U$.

Now, that implies that if $f(x) \sim_{x\to x_0} 0$, one must have $\varepsilon$ and $U$ as above such that
$$
\lvert f(x) \rvert\leq \varepsilon(x)\cdot 0 = 0, \qquad \forall x\in U
$$
and consequently $f$ has to be identically $0$ on $U$.